# PDOException - could not find driver - Unable to update the database scheme by php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update the schema of mysql database by doctorine

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

it shows

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php/5.3.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php/5.3.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_pdo_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0


  [PDOException]         
  could not find driver
```

it looks like extension is not available.

but according to my phpinfo();

pdo_mysql is enabled.

```
pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id:     e707c415db32080b3752b232487a435ee0372157 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket    /tmp/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Is there any other point to check for me?

I also tried comment or uncomment this line in php.ini

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: restart all services of webserver again. nd check is it still happening..

Comment: @Rahul: it's a CLI problem, so there is no webserver involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using php in CLI, which may not be configured the same way as php, the module of your webserver.

This means that if you want information about php CLI, you should try `php -i` in cli, not request a script with a call to `phpinfo()`. More simply, to check which modules are loaded in CLI, run `php -m`.

And also, to know which ini files are loaded in CLI, use `php --ini`.

Comment: oh ,great hint!,phpinfo() shows using /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini , but php -i shows  using /usr/local/Cellar/php/5.3.10/etc/php.ini. How can I change the php.ini file of CLI?

Comment: I don't know, I suppose you have to recompile php, or always run it with some option. If it is in order to have the same configuration file, I advise you not to. There are things, like the `memory_limit` setting, that you'll want to keep separate. If you still want to have the same file, I guess you can replace the php.ini for cli with a symlink to the other one.